# How to recycle SKSpriteNodes with animations

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, cpu, skspritenode

I'm making my first game in Swift and SpriteKit and I have ran into countless CPU issues in which I approach 100% of CPU after a couple minutes of game play. It seems like this shouldnt happen, as I'm really only drawing 20ish animated enemies at a time. While it's not the only problem, I believe that instantiating my enemy class is contributing heavily to this overuse.

In my code, I instantiate a new enemy alien every couple of seconds. I am fairly certain that I am removing them properly- either on contact or when they move off screen. So I believe my next attempt should be to try and recycle them instead of continually completely removing and adding them.

I'm adding with:

```
func addNormAlien(){
    let mult = normAlienMultiplers

    let alienInst = normAlien(startPos:CGPoint(x: 10,y: 10), speed: random(UInt32(10), max: UInt32(50))*mult[0])

    let yStart = random(UInt32(alienInst.size.height/2), max: UInt32(size.height-alienInst.size.height))
    alienInst.position = CGPoint(x:size.width+alienInst.size.width/2, y:yStart)

    addChild(alienInst)
    totalNodes+=1
}
```

and removing with the general statement: `alien.removeFromParent()` in both contact methods and in update if it's x position is past a certain point.

I was thinking that I could create an array (or queue?) of some sort that would fit some max number and that I could push them on and off of that. Is there a proper way to go about recycling SKSpriteNode subclasses like this? P.S. what is the appropriate range of CPU use-- when testing on iPhone?

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to do this now. As this is your first game, and as someone that has answered some of your questions before, you want to follow the K.I.S.S model. Given that you have only "20ish" enemies, then it is indicative that either you have way more than 20 or you are doing something bad in your code. Even if you go to an object queue, you may get some performance gains, but your code will not be fixed and you'll run into other problems. I had previously made some suggestions on how to approach the problem of CPU and I sort of doubt you did them all.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should take a look [at the prototype pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/prototype.html). You basically create each enemy only the first time and clone them for use in the game. At least this should reduce file system interaction (loading of textures, etc…).

Comment: I don't think I understand-- isn't that "cloning" process just as intensive but also saves a state? Also for a relatively straightforward 2D game like this what would you say an appropriate CPU use is on device?

Comment: I assume you reload textures from the filesystem each time you create an enemy. Filesystem interactions are usually slow. By creating a prototype and only loading a single time and just cloning the enemy each time you need to use them, you would reduce this to just memory interactions, which are much more speedy. Alternatively you could preload all textures into a static class, which might be a simpler approach.

Comment: You should also check the node count (property on SKScene) to make sure nodes get removed properly.

Comment: Wrt CPU use, SpriteKit should easily be able to handle your use-case, as long as you are not using SKShapeNodes. SKShapeNodes are very slow and should mostly be used for debugging.